# RoR sum related records during controller create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tables = expenses and invlines (invoice lines).

Expense belongs_to Invline

Invline has_many expenses

Using the Invlines input form, I have the user select the Expenses.

When the Invlines record is saved, I would like to summarize the expenses and place into invline.price

In the Invlines controller I'm trying to use:

```
def create
@invline = Invline.new(params[:invline])
@invline.price ||= @invline.expenses.amount.sum
```

But, I get

```
undefined method `amount'
```

Ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
@invline.price ||= @invline.expenses.amount.sum
```

with

```
@invline.price ||= @invline.expenses.sum(:amount)
```

The `.expenses` call returns a list of expenses, but only a particular expense has `amount`.